# Is possible to lock a NFC tag and later unlock and write data again?

Tags: android, nfc, rfid

I'm developing a NFC app that will have tags in public places, and in this way it would be necessary to lock the tags with a password or other tool, to avoid that someone deletes the information or modifies their content. The tags should be updatable at a later time. So, is possible to do this? Or when I lock a tag, does it stay read-only forever?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This very much depends on the type (and consequently price) of NFC tag that you use. Typical, cheap NFC tags (e.g. Type 1 tags like Topaz/Jewel or Type 2 tags like MIFARE Ultralight, NTAG203, Kovio 2K, or my-d NFC) do not allow this. They can only be *permanently* write-protected (and this is what you should typically do when installing tags in public places).

Other tags do provide some form authentication-based access control that can be used to restrict write-access tag memory, e.g.

- MIFARE Ultralight C: mutual challenge response authentication using 3DES
- NTAG21x, MIFARE Ultralight EV1, my-d move NFC: password based "authentication" with clear-text password. Be warned that a clear-text password may have sever security implications.
- MIFARE DESFire (EV1): mutual challenge response authentication using DES, 3DES or AES
- ...

Authentication is not part of the NFC Forum's tag operation specifications and is consequently tag/tag manufacturer dependent. In order to use such advanced functionality on Android, you would need to implement the relevant commands youself (using the `tech.transceive()` method).

Note that `Ndef.makeReadOnly()` on Android does not necessarily set any hardware lock bits. This method may in some cases just as well only set a write protection on protocol level (i.e. set a flag that requests the NFC device not to write any data, but don't protect the actual data pages from being overwritten).

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course but Android API don't have ready-made method to do it.
You have to use APDU to control access to tag.

The Ndef class has a makeReadOnly method: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/Ndef.html#makeReadOnly() but you can't unlock tag.

Comment: Hi Laurent: Can we lock/unlock NFC with password?? There are apps in market in which we can lock/unlock NFC with password if you have any information then do let me know.